# How do I relocate assemblies from a deployment project without breaking application references?

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, assemblies

I have recently refactored a lot of my applications existing code and I am now looking at tidying up the deployment side of things.

The existing installer application installs everything in the application folder (with the exclusion of a couple of config files which are located in a sub folder). However, I have multiple applications which all use some common assemblies and my goal is to relocate these particular assemblies to the *"Common Files"* folder in the program files directory.

*NB: I have read a lot about the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but I have no experience with it and also read a few horror stories, so trying to get a simple solution for the time being.*

I managed to get the assemblies installed into the Common Files folder, however, as a result (*typical I.T.*) I have broken my app! If I copy the assemblies back into the application folder it works fine so the problem is obviously to do with how my app is referencing the assemblies.

To get the installer to install the assemblies into the Common Files folder I just updated the `Folder` property of each assembly in the `Detected Dependencies` list. My thoughts were when I did that the installer would somehow update my application to tell it to look in that folder for them but that doens't appear to be the case.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no requirements for assemblies to be in the GAC, unless the developer of an application/library designed it so. You have the choice to write you application so that most (if not all) referenced assemblies load from a specified (Common Files) location.

Here's an example architecture that implements the technologies described in the MSDN articles referenced at the bottom of this response.

Example: In an SOA application you might have a couple of different (Windows) services. Services could be load balanced across multiple servers. Within each server, services can be installed under a 'Services' directory. Services living in the 'Services' directory could share assemblies from a (Common Files) 'lib' directory:

```
\CompanyName
      \Services
           \Service1
           \Service2
           \Service3
      \lib
```

Every actual service would derive from a Base Service class that would make use of an Assembly Utility. Your Assembly Utility could be configured to search for assemblies in a systematic way, allowing you to use shared/common assemblies. The neat thing is that your application could run with local assemblies (in local development) but use shared assemblies when deployed.

In my real world example, I had the luxury of having custom build and deployment scripts. Think of the different scenarios you can have deploying 1 of N services. Do you always update the (Common Files) 'lib' directory? Can a service run with local assemblies different than the 'lib' assemblies? Etc.

I hope this was helpful. If your issue is getting a third-party installer to deploy your application correctly, then disregard and name the installer. Otherwise, the given example/solution should help :o)

Read on the subject at MSDN:

- [Programming With Application Domains and Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dah4cwez.aspx)
- [Resolving Assembly Loads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx)
- [ResolveEventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resolveeventhandler.aspx)

PS: I've had challenges resolving assemblies for Microsoft's Unity framework.

Comment: +1 thanks Omar. This will definitely help me out.  So your hinting at introducing a custom domain and overriding the AppDomain.Load/Assemby.Load methods?

Comment: I'm not sure how loosely you're using "custom" but yes your managed code should run under the same domain. The way I've done it is by having an assembly resolving utility, which I think could be a factory.


Application Domains (MSDN) -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to "reference" some assemblies from common folder, it is possible at development time. However when deploying every application has to have those individual assemblies installed with them.

If at run time, more than one of your applications are sharing some assemblies then "that common folder" is GAC.

Comment: Yes they will be sharing the assemblies at run-time so does that mean that it *has* to be the GAC?

Comment: Well GAC is the place to do such things. However I encountered this article http://weblogs.asp.net/chrismoseley/archive/2008/10/28/shared-assemblies-without-the-gac.aspx. See if it helps you.

Comment: Interesting article. It relates to ASP.NET specifically, however, I will see how it goes and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: the NTFS junction points is a neat trick as well, indeed! and has nothing to do with asp.net.